# Laravel on ubuntu not triggering certain commands?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-forge

I am running laravel forge on AWS with ubuntu, the problem appears simple but I don't know why it's happening.

Here's my scheduler:

```
    $schedule->command('scrape:cinema')
             ->dailyAt('4:00')
             ->sendOutputTo($log);
    $schedule->command('ical:download')
             ->hourly()
             ->sendOutputTo($log);
    $schedule->command('ical:convert')
             ->hourly()
             ->sendOutputTo($log);
    $schedule->command('events:forcedelete')
             ->dailyAt('2:00')
             ->sendOutputTo($log);
    $schedule->command('events:recalculate')
            ->dailyAt('2:15')
            ->sendOutputTo($log);
    $schedule->command('event:clear')
             ->everyTenMinutes()
             ->sendOutputTo($log);
}
```

Now the scheduler is being triggered every minute and for example command('event:clear') is being triggered, however command such as events:recalculate isn't. I noticed it is because it has a set time so at 2:15. if I change it to ->everyMinute() for example it works fine. Anyone knows what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you try `->dailyAt('02:15')`?

Comment: I tried ->dailyAt('11:00') so it should be triggered one minute ago and it didn't

Comment: Have you checked the log file for errors?